# Log inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

Solve the inequality

$\log(5^{1/x} +5^3) < \log 6 + \log 5^{1+\frac{1}{2x}}$

I came up with an equation

$5^{\frac{4x-1}{2x}} + 5^{\frac{-2x+1}{2x}}-6<0$

Which I couldn't solve, i tried to make it quadratic but I couldn't

Comment: Are you sure with that?

Comment: For $x=\dfrac12$ one has  $LHS=RHS\approx 2.176091259$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality you've got looks correct (presumably it comes from exponentiating both sides, then dividing by $5^{1+1/(2x)}$).

Hint to continue from here: write $y=5^{1-1/(2x)}$ and rearrange to get an equation in $y$.

Comment: I think his inequality isn't correct!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think you have copied the question incorrectly in your answer - the RHS has $5^{1+1/2x}$, not $5^{1+1/x}$.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your hint!

Comment: thanks! i got it now

Comment: is it between 1/4 and 1/2?

Comment: @EspeciallyLime the substitution should be $y=5^{\frac{1}{2x}}$

Comment: @SuperMage1 Yes the result is$\frac 14 < x < \frac 12$.

Answer (score 4):

By the logarithm rule we get
$$\log(5^{1/x}+5^3)<\log(6\cdot 5^{1+1/2x})$$
so we get

$$5^{1/x}+5^3<6\cdot 5^{1+1/2x}$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since $\log$ function is **monotonic increasing** we have

$$\log(5^{1/x}+5^3)<\log(6\cdot 5^{1+1/2x})\iff 5^{1/x}+5^3<6\cdot 5^{1+1/2x}$$

that is

$$5^{1/x-1-1/2x}+5^{3-1-1/2x}<6$$

and then your result

> $$5^{\frac{4x-1}{2x}}+5^{\frac{1-2x}{2x}}-6<0$$

then

$$5^{2-\frac{1}{2x}}+5^{\frac{1}{2x}-1}-6<0$$

$$25\cdot 5^{-\frac{1}{2x}}+\frac15 \cdot 5^{\frac{1}{2x}}-6<0$$

that is by $y=5^{\frac{1}{2x}}$

$$\frac{25}y+\frac y 5-6<0 \implies y^2-30y+125<0$$

$$y=\frac{30\pm\sqrt{900-500}}{2}=15\pm 10 \implies 5<y<25$$

that is, observing that exponential function is **monotonic increasing**

$$5<5^{\frac{1}{2x}}<25=5^2$$

$$1<\frac{1}{2x}<2 \iff \frac12 <2x <1 \iff \frac 14 < x < \frac 12$$